# Simulink - Use .Mat as extern input variable to auto-coded c function

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model that I was able to auto-code. I set some of the inputs (vx,vy,vz, x,y,z) that I needed to change as extern, and this works fine so far. Now I need access to the .Mat data file (think GPS almanac data) that will change based on test week. Instead of having to re-autocode with the new .Mat in my workspace it would be great if I could set that as an extern and feed it data from my .cpp wrapper like the rest of the variables. Any tips would be awesome!

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Comment: Okay I made a simple example. Is there any way to upload the .slx and .mat file here? Or I can take screenshots of everything.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I added pictures if that helps

Answer (score 2):

The `-p` optional input to the Rapid Simulation Target is designed for this purpose, although the format of the .mat file must be of a specific type.

An example can be found here: [Using RSIM target over range of parameter values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/examples/using-rsim-target-for-parameter-survey.html).

It shows creating the mat file in MATLAB, but it could be created in C or C++ using the appropriate mat file API: [MAT-File API Library and Include Files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/mat-file-library-and-include-files.html)

Comment: I added pictures if that would help. I didn't quite follow the RSIM read through.

Comment: How simplified is the data set you have shown?  Given the images above, I'd suggest making `alm_data` (or even just the health column if that's all that is needed) an input to the `MATLAB Function` block, then it's value can be obtained from the workspace in exactly the same was as `theta` and `omega` are in the linked example.

Comment: EDIT: Couldn't figure out how to format so I posted in the main question. Thank you for the help so far! the matlab code gets more complicated. It utilizes every column/variable, and uses them in  a loop. I can edit the init function, but there's an init function:
    alm_data = coder.load('alm_data.mat');
    %init vector sizes
    ps=zeros(3,length(alm_data.alm_data); %more of this
    end
then used in loop:
for i =1:length(alm_data.alm_data)
    vs=alm_pos_vel(alm_data.alm_data(i));
    %more of this
end

Comment: I like the idea of sending in the individual columns as vectors from c++, but is there a way to rebuild them as a .mat within my init function so it doesn't mess up the rest of the m-file?